# How can I change maximumBillingTier?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

I am testing BigQuery tables and I saw that I can modify the maximumBillingTier in order to require a large amount of resources to process per byte of source data but it is not clear to me how can I modify this filed.

Can you show an example? how can I modify this field?

It is possible to change this value per query? as mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#high-compute)

Can I also change in on WEB UI? I found no document showing how can this be accomplished

Answer (score 2):

To run the query at a higher pricing tier, pass a new value for maximumBillingTier

> configuration.query.maximumBillingTier

as part of the query request, the same way as you pass other properties
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs#configuration.query

like below for example

> configuration.query.createDisposition or configuration.query.allowLargeResults

Please note: The maximumBillingTier is a positive integer that serves as a multiplier of the basic price of $5 per TB. see more at
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#high-compute

if you want to make it from within bq command line -

```
USAGE: bq.py [--global_flags] <command> [--command_flags] [args]
```

try to play with below global flag

> --job_property: Additional key-value pairs to include in the properties field   of the job configuration;   repeat this option to
>   specify a list of values

Comment: Thanks you! But if I want to change if at command line? how can I do it?
For example: bq query  "SELECT word FROM publicdata:samples.shakespeare"
how can I pass this value? and how can I make sure I have maximumBillingTier with different value?

Comment: I tried by myself and got no success at all. Even using maximumBillingTier in API i was not able to prevent query with billing tier 6 (as an example) to be successfuly completed. Also, when using API Explorer - it says that maximumBillingTier is not recognized parameter. Hopefully someone from Google Team will jump here and clear this

Comment: The only potential explanation i see so far is that this will be effective since 1/1/2016 - but this sounds fishy to me

Comment: Mikhail,

Take a look at the docs here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#high-compute

In short, all queries are treated as Tier 1 queries until 1/1/16. For projects created prior to 1/1/16, they get this behavior until October 1, 2016, and you may opt out at any time.

Comment: @vgt - if you check my answer - i already referenced this link. But it doesnt answer above specifics

Comment: As per this [link](https://support.google.com/cloud/contact/bigquery_high_compute_queries_quota_request_form) "By default, users can override the maximumBillingTier for a specific query by passing a new value for maximumBillingTier as part of the query" It is possible to pass a new value to maximumBillingTier using the BigQuery Web UI?

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant Can you provide me with an example of a billing tier 6 query?

Comment: format for comments is not friendly enough for presenting such examples. anyway - i see some examples of high billing tier queries among different users from different departments. these are few most recent patterns: #1 - tier=3,4 - simple group by field that is relatively bushy case statement and just simple count() as aggregation against relatively small (at least in our business) table of 1.6B rows; #2 - tier=5-10 - select of 50-60 filelds off of joins of 10-15 tables with group by about 40-45 fields. Hope this gave you an idea.

Answer (score 1):

The bq.py command line client does not yet expose a flag to set the `maximumBillingTier` for a query. This is in the works so look for an update soon.

Comment: How can I change the maximumBillingTier then? It is possible to do it over Web UI?