# Did Billing Tier on BigQuery change?

Tags: google-bigquery

we have been running a query on BigQuery for the last couple of weeks, and it has been executing fine. However, as of the morning of February 16 2016, it would only run at billing tier 2. Did Google change the billing tier definitions internally over the weekend as a Valentine's gift? ...

More seriously, it is important to communicate these changes (well) ahead of time.

Comment: Update: we figured out what caused our query to jump billing tiers. We are casting a float to a string and that chops off the float to the 4th decimal. So we started doing STRING(INTEGER(x)+x-INTEGER(x)) which, in contrast to STRING(x) does *not* chop off the decimals. Well, that caused the bump to billing tier 2. We since modified this to STRING(x*1) which also does not chop off decimals, but does not jump to a higher tier. By the way, the behavior of FLOAT under STRING casting is a bit weird, as you can tell...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apologies for the surprise!

This change is part of our new high-compute query pricing, which is documented here:

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#high-compute

The original announcement of the high-compute query pricing plan was here:

http://googlecloudplatform.blogspot.com/2015/08/Google-BigQuery-adds-UDF-support-for-deeper-cloud-analytics.html

This change was originally intended to go live earlier in the year, but was delayed for several weeks. I've rolled it back once again, but you should expect it to get rolled forward soon (weeks, if not days).

If you have additional questions or concerns, feel free to contact support, post here, or file a bug on our issue tracker:

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/support

For more info about high-compute queries, see this SO answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/32638711/1375400

Comment: Can you give an example of the type of query that might require high-compute pricing? Is it more likely to be driven by complexity of the query, number of tables, size of the tables, or all?

Comment: Roughly speaking, there's a CPU budget per byte processed, and if you exceed that budget you get bumped to the next tier. Increasing number or size of tables will increase bytes processed and should not trigger high-compute queries. Increased query complexity, especially UDFs, fancy regexps, joins, and so on, are more likely culprits. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/32638711/1375400.