# Does Google BigQuery charge by processing time?

Tags: google-bigquery

So, this is somewhat of a "realtime" question. I run a query and it's currently going at almost 12K seconds, but it told me `This query will process 239.3 GB when run.` Does BQ charge by the time besides the data processed? Should I stop this now?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using on-demand pricing model - you are billed based on amount of processed bytes and processing time is not involved

- BigQuery uses a columnar data structure. You're charged according to the total data processed in the columns you select, and the total data per column is calculated based on the types of data in the column. For more information about how your data size is calculated, see data size calculation.
- You aren't charged for queries that return an error, or for queries that retrieve results from the cache.
- Charges are rounded to the nearest MB, with a minimum 10 MB data processed per table referenced by the query, and with a minimum 10 MB data processed per query.
  Cancelling a running query job may incur charges up to the full cost for the query were it allowed to run to completion.
- When you run a query, you're charged according to the data processed in the columns you select, even if you set an explicit LIMIT on the results.

See more at [BigQuery pricing](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing)

Comment: so, in short, no. I'm not charged by processing time, but just ingested bytes... that's what I read you're saying there

Comment: I'm curious, how much did you actually get charged for your 12k seconds, 240GB query?

Answer (score 0):

For on-demand queries you are charged for the amount of data processed by BigQuery engine and for expensive queries only you are charged extra for the complexity (which could manifest itself by increased query time).

The amount of data processed is reflected by `totalBytesProcessed`. And also by `totalBytesBilled` which is the same for ordinary queries. For complex/expensive queries you are charged extra for the complexity and technically it's done by `totalBytesBilled` becoming bigger than `totalBytesProcessed`.

More details: see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32638711/12005425)