# How to calculate IO for a query in google bigquery for write operations

Tags: google-bigquery

I am going through all the java-docs that are available on google side to find the IO for a query, there is a field called [totalBytesProcessed](https://javadoc.io/static/com.google.cloud/google-cloud-bigquery/1.82.0/com/google/cloud/bigquery/JobStatistics.QueryStatistics.html#getTotalBytesProcessed--), but the totalBytesProcessed field tells you how much data is **processed ([read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32626848/totalbytesbilled-is-different-from-totalbytesprocessed))** by your query. For the write queries i am not getting that field populated [itself](https://javadoc.io/static/com.google.cloud/google-cloud-bigquery/1.82.0/com/google/cloud/bigquery/JobStatistics.QueryStatistics.html#getTotalBytesProcessed--). Now in this case how can i see the IO of a query ? We have fields related to queryOutput, and [DmlStats](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/DmlStats) but those are just number of rows effected, we can't calculate the bytes based on number of rows, since from row to row the bytes can vary. In order to conclude my question, is there any way i can know the noOfBytesProcessed for write operations queries.

Comment: [‘getTotalBytesProcessed’](https://javadoc.io/static/com.google.cloud/google-cloud-bigquery/1.82.0/com/google/cloud/bigquery/JobStatistics.QueryStatistics.html#getTotalBytesProcessed–) should work because this function returns the number of bytes processed by the job; it doesn't matter if it is a select or an insert.

Comment: I have seen for the insert  query which inserted 90k rows, the totalBytesProcessed field was given 0, seen this multiple times. you can also check this reference 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32626848/totalbytesbilled-is-different-from-totalbytesprocessed